# Create a form in rails by reading a yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to create a form by reading a yml file. I'm able to read the file properly but I'm not sure how to place the items in the hash properly into the code that creates the forms.
For example, my yml file reads something like

```
-  f.label: :email
   f.email_field: :email

-  f.label: :name
   f.text_field: :name
```

I read the yml file in my controller like this

```
@form_format = YAML::load(File.open('public/grant.yml'))
```

and the code in my view is something like this

```
<%= form_for(:submission, url: submissions_path) do |f| %>
    <% @form_format.each do |item| %>
        <% item.each do |key, value| %>
           <%= key value %>
           <%= key value %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
   <%= f.submit "Apply", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I know that it's the <%= key value %> bit that's not correct but I'm not sure how to get it to read <%= f.label: :email %> for example from the values in the hash.

The overall reason I'm trying to figure this out is because I need to create many (100+) unique forms and I thought the best way I could do this is to create a unique "schema" in a yml file for each form and read the schema in to create the fields. If there are other ways that are better to do this, I'm all ears. I'm fairly new to RoR but I've searched extensively and haven't found much. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just put that in your migration file?

Comment: Sorry - not sure what you mean. The overall reason I'm trying to figure this out is because I need to create many (100+) unique forms and I thought the best way I could do this is to create a unique "schema" in a yml file for each form and read the schema in to create the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! However, this will be much easier if your YAML has just `label` instead of `f.label`, like so:

```
- label: :email
  email_field: :email

- label: :name
  text_field: :name
```

Once you've loaded this YAML you'll have a Ruby array that looks like this:

```
[ { "label" => "email",
    "email_field" => "email"
  },
  { "label" => "name",
    "text_field" => "name"
  }
]
```

The trick is that for each of the hashes we can use the keys as method names to send to the `f` object.

Supposing you've assigned the array to `@form_format` in your controller, it'll look like this in your view:

```
<%= form_for(:submission, url: submissions_path) do |f| %>
  <% @form_format.each do |item| %>
    <% item.each do |type, name| %>
      <%= f.send(type, name) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```